# Loading Iris data into MLPClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter

I am attempting to load `url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data`
and split this file in Jupyter but continue to get multiple errors. I am new to programing and in desperate need of assistance.  I have spent numerous hours on attempting to rectify the errors.
`Error messages: "indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)", "raise TypeError("Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key")" TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key`
I am also attempting to split the data into test and training.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(['data'], ['target'], random_state=0)
```

Assistance in requested.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
#from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(['data'], ['target'], random_state=0)
```

Comment: The values `['data']` and `['target']` that  you're passing to `train_test_split` are just lists of string, you need to pass data. @Roei Levy's answer is correct. Use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can load directly the iris data from sklearn:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
data = load_iris()
```

Then split:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(data.data,data.target,test_size=0.5)
```

Comment: thank you Roei Levy, but more errors have been generated. I have not used the cross_validation before.

Comment: 'train_test_split' function is the same whether you load it via 'cross_validation' or 'model_selection', so you can use the above with the latter instead.